# Anyone know how it would be possible to change the cursor in a UITextView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

A customer has requested that they want the cursor in the UITextView to be horizontal instead of vertical. Anyone know how I might do that as there isn't any public API to modify the cursor.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want that..?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do it in uitextview. If you're determined, you could write a new text editor using Core Text and render the cursor however you like. That's a lot of work though.